# WinJS - How to read the value of an item in a Listview

Tags: windows-8, winjs, windows-8.1

What is the best or suggested way to get an item from a ListView control in WinJS?

**This:**

```
var listView = document.getElementById("listView").winControl;
var item = listView.itemDataSource.itemFromIndex(0);
var name = item._value.data.firstName
```

**Or this:**

```
var listView = document.getElementById("listView").winControl;
var item = listView.itemDataSource._list.getAt(i);
var name = item.firstame
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you query the result of the promise you can read the data of the item:

```
var item, name;

listView.itemFromIndex(0).done(function (result) {

    if (result) {

        item = result;

        name = item.data.firstName;

    }

 }, function() {

      //Your error handler here

 });
```

Tip - Both of your examples contain private variables (prefixed with _) - usually a sign that it's not good practice to be accessing these.

Comment: I know about the private one, but could really not find any other way and I didnøt notice that itemFromIndex was returning a promise. Thanks for this